# Formatear una fecha string en C#

Tags: c#, string, date, formato

Bien, se que esto es algo sencillo pero no uso c# hace un tiempo.

Tengo una fecha en formato **STRING** "01/12/2022" y necesito llevarla a este otro formato "2022-12-01"

Osea, invertido y con guiones. Alguna idea de como hacerlo? Deben mantenerse como string al final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convirtiendo a Datetime

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("01/12/2022");
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); //2022-12-01
```

2. Haciendo split + reverse + join

Es decir, se convierte en un array con {dia,mes,año}, se hace un reverse quedando {año,mes,dia} y luego un join("-") para unir el array quedando año-mes-dia

```
string fecha = "01/12/2022";
string fecha2 = string.Join("-", fecha.Split('/').Reverse());
Console.WriteLine(fecha2); //2022-12-01
```

Comment: Si quiere leer un formato en particular, puede usar [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact). Por ejemplo `DateTime.ParseExact("01/12/2022", "dd/MM/yyyy")`

Answer (score 1):

También puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse("01/12/2022");

Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2}", fecha.Year, fecha.Month, fecha.Day);
```

Conviertes la cadena a un tipo **DateTime**, y una vez convertida accedes individualmente a las propiedades deseadas dando el formato deseado.

Si quieres guardar en una variable puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
string fechaInvertida = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", fecha.Year, fecha.Month, fecha.Day);

Console.WriteLine(fechaInvertida);
```

Comment: Sirve, aunque luego tendria que convertirlo de nuevo a string al finalizar. Gracias

Comment: @AldahirRuizValdez revisa lo nuevo q puse

Comment: Genial, gracias, justamente habia hecho lo mismo en el projecto. Ambas soluciones funcionan igual de bien, es una pena no poder marcar ambas como correctas