# ¿Como puedo cambiar el formato de una fecha?

Tags: c#

Necesito cambiar el formato de la fecha para obtener una lista desde la base de datos el problema que tengo es que me llega en este formato 26-12-2022 y necesito 2022-12-26

```
 public ActionResult GetInforme(int? idOrden, DateTime fechaInicio, DateTime fechaFinal)
    {
        idOrden = idOrden ?? 0;
        var fecha = fechaInicio.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var data = db.Pedido.Where(x => x.IdCliente== idOrden && x.Vigente == true && x.Fecha == fechaInicial. && x.FechaEntrega == fechaFinal).ToList();
        return View(data);
    }
```

el resultado en string no me sirve ya que el dato debe ser una datetime

Comment: Entra aki https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/573868/formatear-una-fecha-string-en-c/574043#574043

Comment: Y por qué en vez de utilizar var, no utilizas un DateTime ?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato estás usando en la base de datos, la tienes como DATE, DATETIME o VARCHAR?